# Why does 'git stash apply' stage my changes?

Tags: git

I make a change and then I `git stash` and then I `git stash apply`

My question is

1. why after I `git stash apply`, my change becomes 'staged'? i.e. I won't see anything if I do `git diff`, I only see my difference if I do `git diff --cached`?
2. Is there anyway to 'unstage' my changes staged by `git stash apply` command?
3. Is there any git command basically let me to 'make a backup of my change, reset it to the HEAD and the copy my backup back'?  I thought `git stash` and then `git stash apply` is that command, but some how it 'staged' all my changes? Is there any equivalent which let me `git stash apply` without the staged my changes part?

Comment: `git stash apply` doesn't stage saved changes for me. Can you post a more details of what you are doing?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you find that your changes are unexpectedly staged, do:

```
git reset HEAD
```

I usually only see this if there is a conflict when applying the stashed changes. You will want to check to see whether this is the case before doing the `git reset`.

The `git stash` command is the most appropriate command for your use case. I use it all the time for exactly this purpose.

Answer (score 13):

> Why does git stash apply stage my changes?

Anything that will affect your working tree ([like a `git checkout -- afile`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39406377/6309)) will first affect your index.

> the index is the middle-man for moving things from your work-tree to the object-store AND for moving things from the object-store to your work-tree.

The index is also used by `git stash apply` for recording merge conflicts, as the [index has stage-n entries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25806452/6309). See [`git merge`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge):

> For conflicting paths, the index file records up to three versions:
>
> - stage 1 stores the version from the common ancestor,
> - stage 2 from HEAD, and
> - stage 3 from MERGE_HEAD (you can inspect the stages with `git ls-files -u`).

In the history of the evolution of `git stash --apply`, two interesting events are to be noted:
In April 2011 (Git 1.7.5.1, [commit e0e2a9c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e0e2a9cbfa938d0f1e9857d5ca5b196360663440)), `stash` dropped the dirty worktree check on apply.

> Before we apply a stash, we make sure there are no changes in the worktree that are not in the index. This check dates back to the original `git-stash.sh`, and is presumably intended to prevent changes in the working tree from being accidentally lost during the merge.
>
> However, this check has two problems:
>
> 1. It is overly restrictive. If my stash changes only file "`foo`", but "`bar`" is dirty in the working tree, it will prevent us from applying the stash.
> 2. It is redundant. We don't touch the working tree at all until we actually call merge-recursive.
>      But it has its own (much more accurate) checks to avoid losing working tree data, and will abort the merge with a nicer message telling us which paths were problems.
>
> So we can simply drop the check entirely.

Using the index to manage the merge done by a `git stash apply` lead to another bug, detected in April 2015, Git 2.4.2, [commit ed178ef](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ed178ef13a26136d86ff4e33bb7b1afb5033f908):

> ### `stash`: require a clean index to apply
>
> If you have staged contents in your index and run "`stash apply`", we may hit a conflict and put new entries into the index.
>   **Recovering to your original state is difficult at that point, because tools like "`git reset --keep`" will blow away anything staged**.
>   We can make this safer by refusing to apply when there are staged changes.

Answer (score 4):

I think that something may be wrong in your configuration as while `git stash` records the state of the index and the working tree before resetting to the latest commit, `git stash apply` should only attempt to restore the state of the index if you use the `--index` option.

One possible point of confusion is that if you have conflict (i.e. there are merge conflicts introduced because the stash is being applied to a different commit where the files affected by the stash have been changed since the commit at which the stash was made), then if you use `mergetool` to resolve the conflicts, `mergetool` will automatically stage changes to the files on a successful resolution.

As Greg Hewgill states a simple reset will unstage all staged changes.

```
git reset
```

Comment: I have the exact same problem as the OP.
when git stash apply gives a conflict, changes are staged.

I do not use any tool for conflict resolution, only my code editor.
Any other suggestion about who is staging the stashed changes?

Note: msysgit on windows!

Comment: The only config that comes remotely close to a culprit would be core.logallrefupdates = true, but I doubt, it has to do something with it.