# git "reset" workdir to HEAD without touching staging area

Tags: git

Using the same table representation as in `git-reset` manual page, I have these states in my `git` repository:

```
working index HEAD
------------------
 B       B     A
```

What command will change the states to those?

```
working index HEAD
------------------
 A       B     A
```

I other word, I want to "reset" the  working directory state to the `HEAD` state, but without touching the staging area state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A plumbing way of doing this is to manually backup and restore the index before and after doing `git checkout`:

```
cp .git/index .git/index.bak
git checkout HEAD -- .
mv .git/index.bak .git/index
```

Comment: simple and elegant!

Comment: FU******ING GIT!

Answer (score 4):

As noted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59666788), there is now a native git command which does this:

```
git restore --source=HEAD --worktree -- .
```

See [the manpage](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore).

Answer (score 2):

I assume this should work (ordering matters).

You will first need to commit what is in the index (to make the HEAD look like this index and the working directory: B -- using your annotations):

```
git commit
```

So, the HEAD will be B (using your annotations).

Now, print the reflog as we will need the hash of B:

```
git reflog
```

Now, run a couple of `reset` commands with different options:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~ # makes the working directory, the index, and the HEAD looks like this: A, A, A (respectively)
git reset --mixed <hashOfB> # makes the working directory, the index, and the HEAD looks like this: A, B, B (respectively)
git reset --soft HEAD~ # makes the working directory, the index, and the HEAD looks like this: A, B, A (respectively)
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I believe this does work, based on a quick test I just did.

Answer (score 1):

As discusses in [this thread](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/Can-I-checkout-a-single-file-without-altering-index-td5626080.html), I thought initially about git checkout but:

> FWIW, my understanding of the index is that it is the middle-man for moving
>   things from your work-tree to the object-store AND for moving things from
>   the object-store to your work-tree.
>   Therefore, when you checkout the blob, it first gets copied from the object-store to your index and then from the index to your work-tree.

So (same thread)

> If you want to bypass the index, you can do so with `cat-file` or `show`; it just is not a useful operation in a normal workflow of building the next
>   commit on top of the current one, and that is the only reason why there
>   is no option such as "`checkout --no-index HEAD~47 path`".  If somebody
>   can write a convincing use case that shows why it is useful, such an
>   option shouldn't be very hard to add.

```
git show @:myFile > myFile
```

You can do that directly from the folder where your file is, with a relative path:

```
git show @:./myFile > myFile
```

Comment: For more, see my older answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2910431/6309, and http://stackoverflow.com/a/610315/6309

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do this on a file by file basis :

```
# for each staged file :
git show A:path/to/file > path/to/file
```

`git show A:path/to/file` will output the content of said file in commit `A`.

---

Not exactly what you ask for : using `git stash`, you can keep a backup of your current index in the stash :

```
# optional : stash away modifications which are *not* in index
$ git stash --keep-index  

# 'git stash save' is the same as 'git stash',
# it only allows to put a more explicit message
$ git stash save "index while working on A"

$ git stash list
stash@{0}: On master: index while working on A
stash@{1}: WIP on master: 57632bc first

# you can access your index by using stash@{0} :
#   git show stash@{0}:file
#   git checkout stash@{0} .
#   git stash apply
#   etc ...
```

Comment: One flaw with `git show` is that `git show` does not run shown objects through the smudge filters. (It probably should, it's high-level-enough to have all the access it needs.)